# Analysis I (Amann, Escher) I.12 Exercise 6 possible error

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

All vector spaces mentioned are over a field $K$.

**Exercise:**

> Let $E$ and $F$ be finite dimensional. Show that $\text{dim}(E \times F) = \text{dim}(E) \text{dim}(F)$.

**Discussion:**

I am rusty with linear algebra, but this makes no sense to me. It would imply that $\text{dim}(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R) = 1$, which sounds ridiculous.

I would like to assume that $\text{dim}(E \times F) = \text{dim}(E) + \text{dim}(F)$ instead and try to prove that. So assume $e_1, \dots, e_m$ and $f_1, \dots, f_n$ are respective bases for $E$ and $F$. Consider the vectors $(e_1, 0_F), \dots, (e_m, 0_F), (0_E, f_1), \dots, (0_E, f_n) \in E \times F$.

I think it is clear that these vectors generate $E \times F$, since the first $m$ vectors give me any element in the first part of the Cartesian product $E \times F$, and the second $n$ vectors give me any element in the second part. Thus we want to show that, given $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{m + n} \in K$,

\begin{align*}
&\lambda_1 (e_1, 0_F) + \dots + \lambda_m (e_m, 0_F) + \lambda_{m + 1} (0_E, f_1) + \dots + \lambda_{m + n} (0_E, f_n) = (0_E, 0_F)\\
&\Rightarrow \lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_{m + n} = 0_K.
\end{align*}

I am not sure if this is a valid argument, but it seems to me that in order to get the first zero in $(0_E, 0_F)$, you need the first $m$ $\lambda$s to be zero, and then for the second zero you need the rest of the $\lambda$s to be zero.

Is this a detailed enough argument? Do I need to make an argument about $E$ being isomorphic to $(E, 0_F)$ and similarly for $F$?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: That is correct. Indeed $\dim(E\times F)=\dim E+\dim F$.

Comment: unless $\times$ is not a $\otimes$, you are right

Comment: @Exodd There is definitely no $\otimes$ in the question. I don't even know what that is. Tensor product?

Comment: Yes, that's the tensor product.